# Change of variables in integral

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

That's theorem from baby Rudin. But I noted that the consider only strictly insreasing function $\varphi$. What about if $\varphi$ is strictly decreasing?

Here's my thought: If $\varphi(t)$ is decreasing then $-\varphi(t)$ is increasing an it maps interval $[A,B]$ onto $[a,b]$. Then $$\int\limits_{A}^{B} f(-\varphi(t))d\alpha(-\varphi(t))=\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x)d\alpha(x).$$ But how to change $-\varphi$ to $\varphi$ in the first integral?

Can anyone give an answer to my question.

Comment: You can prove it by putting a $-$ (minus) sign to the decreasing function, making it increasing.

Comment: @corbah, I made it but what next?

Comment: @corbah, I would be very grateful if you'll help me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's sketch the proof by an example.

Assume $f(t) = -2t+4$ and $[A,B] = [0,2]$.

Assume also $s = -\frac{t}{2}$ and $[a,b] = [0,-1]$ We know $\varphi(t)= -\frac{t}{2}$ is strictly decreasing.

Then $g(s) = 4s+4$ (Because theorem assumes $g = f$ on their domains translated by $\varphi$.)

$$\int\limits_{0}^{2} f(t)dt = \int\limits_{0}^{2} (-2t+4)dt = 4$$

$$\int\limits_{0}^{-1} g(s)(-2)ds = \int\limits_{-1}^{0} g(s)(2)ds = \int\limits_{-1}^{0} (4s+4)(2)ds = 2.2 = 4$$

Now you see which functions are negated so that we get the same result.

When you negate $\varphi$, Your g function will be re-defined  $g$ function which gives the same result on negated $\varphi$.

Comment: I understood it. But I can't see the relation with above :(